# Cypress| How to count the number of non-empty rows in a table?

Tags: count, cypress, row, emptydatatext

Please help me find a way to count only non-empty table rows. I tried to use it:

```
cy.get("#TableId")
    .find("tr")
    .then((rows) => {
        rows.toArray().forEach((element) => {
        if (element.innerHTML.should('be.not.empty')) {
        //rows.index(element) will give you the row index
           cy.log(rows.index(element));
        }
       });
     });
```

but it throws an error

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: "element.innerHTML.should is not a function"

Comment: I also wanted to try "if (element.innerHTML.includes(text)" but I don't know what to insert instead of "text"

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you are aiming for.

Here's an experiment that uses various expressions, you can pick one that suits your requirements.

Don't forget the add `tbody` to the table selector, since you want to exclude the header row.

**Test HTML**

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span></span></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>some-text</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>some-text</td>
      <td>another-text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Test code**

```js
cy.get('table tbody tr')
  .each((tr, index) => {

    console.group('row', index, tr.html().replaceAll('\n', ''))

    const expressions = [
      "tr.html()", 
      "tr[0].innerHTML", 
      "tr.find('td').toArray().map(td => td.innerHTML).join('')",
      "tr.text()",
      "tr.text().trim().replaceAll('\\n', '')",
    ]
    const results = expressions.reduce((acc,e) => {
      acc[e] = eval(e)
      return acc
    }, {})
    console.table(results)
    console.groupEnd()
  })
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`.should()` and `.includes()` are Cypress validation functions, and should not be used to determine branching. Instead, you can check the `.length` of innerText directly to determine your code path. [(Chai's `.empty` assertion, when run on a String, checks if the length of the variable is 0)](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_empty)

```js
cy.get("#TableId")
    .find("tr")
    .then((rows) => {
        rows.toArray().forEach((element) => {
        if (element.innerHTML.length !== 0) { // may need to use `element.text()` instead of `element.innerHTML`
           cy.log(rows.index(element));
        }
       });
     });
```

Comment: length !== 0 for some reason does not filter lines, both empty and non-empty lines are output to the log.
Perhaps the length is not zero because the cypress counts the cells

Comment: `.length !== 0` may not be the evaluation you want to make, but I was translating your `.should('not.be.empty')` into the same logic that Chai applies for `.be.empty`. Something like `element.innerHTML !== ""` or `element.text().length !== 0` may be the proper solutions, but without an example HTML, I can't really give any exact guidance.